# Why was this question closed as off topic?

Tags: support

Why was this question closed as off topic? Where should question like this be posted?

[Repository vs. UnitOfWork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941573/repository-vs-unitofwork-closed)

To be clear, this is not my question I just answered it. It is more about design than about purely mechanical aspects of programming. But it is a valid software development question. There is no explanation as to why it was closed, just marked as off topic by 5 users. I was a bit surprised when I clicked on users and found that they asked questions like "What is so evil about a Flash based website?" and "Is Code Generation a Bad Thing?". If the reason for closing was 'open endedness' then these question are a lot more open ended.

EDIT:
My conclusion so far is this. On StackOverflow valid design questions may be closed without any explanation. The most likely reason for the question to be closed is being 'open ended'. This is really discouraging because a lot of the problems that developer face today are relatively open ended. Most of the time there is more than one way to solve the problem and this is what voting is for. What is even more disappointing is that the questions are closed randomly by the people who themselves post way more open ended questions.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that there is no objective answer to the question. The responses to the question are just opinions, which could vary from one person to another.

It is similar to asking `Which is better C# or Java?` It depends on whom you ask.

Instead, if you ask which one performs better in a given **programming** scenario with an example of what you did, you might get an answer.

SO is for very specific programming scenarios. [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) might be better fit for this question. `(Please see Anna Lear's comments below).`

Comment: The question is specific, at least it is more specific than "What is so evil about a Flash based website?".

Comment: @Dmitry: Sorry, not exactly. OP hasn't given a specific programming example to deal with. The question seems to cover a broad area not pertaining to one scenario. Yes, you have given programming samples but look at the second answer, it is more of a opinion. So, the question doesn't fit SO even though your answer might. Does that make sense?

Comment: Isn't 'Programmers' for things like career, project management, comradery etc? The question that was closed was specific, was answered with code and hopefully helped the person who asked it. See my conclusions above.

Comment: @Dmitry: Sorry for the confusion. That's why I said **might be** because I am not sure about programmers.SE. I haven't been there much. May be someone more experienced/moderator can chime in better to your question. I just pointed out my interpretation.

Comment: @Dmitry Programmers moderator here. It could be a suitable question for us when phrased from the point of view of determining a best practice. The key distinction between SO and Programmers when it comes to technical questions is that SO is for questions about problems with a specific implementation whereas Programmers is for discussions you'd have in front of a whiteboard.

Comment: Don't you mean "objective" instead of "subjective" (i.e. either "there are only *subjective* answers" or "there are no *objective* answers"?)

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for correcting me. Sorry about the mistake in using a wrong term.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because they felt it was a question asked better on programmers.stackexchange.com. It did not seem to get enough votes though to automatically migrate.

Answer (score 2):

A question that contains "In my point of view", "but X says", and "So what is better?" is a clear candidate for <strike>an off topic</strike> a non-constructive vote. Especially if there is already two answers with different opinions.

What is off topic on SO could easily be on topic somewhere else, but requires that 4 out of 5 voters can agree on exactly *where* to move the question.  This obviously didn't happen here, so it was just agreed that it was off-topic but nothing more.

The fact that you can find other non-good questions is not an argument for adding another one. It is perhaps just that the others are not closed *yet*. The rules seems to have been less strict a couple of years ago (when one of your examples were asked), and some of us were not around to vote at the time.

Some questions also live longer than they might deserve just because they don't attract enough views to collect the required number of close votes.

Comment: What you're describing sounds a lot more like "Not constructive"

Comment: Right, my mind was already in the next paragraph. :-) It might be that I voted for that, but that the off-topic votes were a majority.

Comment: The point of the question is that there is a subtle difference between two well known patterns. The question itself is a request for clarification. I also happen to answer this question in real life few times so it might be useful to more than one person. Both answers are very close to each other so there are no 'different opinions'. Developers face design question as often as they face purely technical questions. We don't want SO to turn into a place where you can only ask about programming language quirks or some framework oddities.